# Count Number of String Matches gives Wrong Result

Tags: java, string, count, string-matching

I want to count the Number of String Matches in a List:
My ArrayList contains:

```
recognise
product
product
process
process
process
principle
partner
particular
```

So that the output should be:

```
recognise 1
product 2
process 3
principle 1
partner 1
particular 1
```

My Code is:

```
List<String> mylist=new LinkedList<String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> result= new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++) {
            mylist.add(wordlist.get(i));   //wordlist contains the above mentioned items
        }
        Collections.sort(mylist);
        Collections.reverse(mylist);

String small="";
int c=0;

for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{
    c+=1;
    small=mylist.get(i);
    for(int j=i;j<mylist.size();j++)
    {
        if(small.contains(mylist.get(j)))
            {
                small=mylist.get(j);

            }
    }
    if (!result.containsKey(small) || result.get(small) < c){
        result.put(small, c);
        c=0;
    }


}
for (String key : result.keySet()){
    System.out.println(key + ": " + result.get(key)); 
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format/indent your code readably.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is count the occurrences of each string in your list, this should suffice:

```
for(String s : mylist) {
    if(result.containsKey(s)) {
        result.put(s, result.get(s) + 1);
    } else {
        result.put(s, 1);
    }
}
```

No need to sort / reverse / etc `mylist`.

To get the count sorted, just use a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) by providing a `Comparator` (I have no prior experience on this, so you better look up the API yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity of your algo seems high of order `O(N^2*length_max)` .
However you can do this in `O(N)` , where N = sum of all strings lengths by making a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) ,
 where each node contains an integer `i` which tells the number of times string ends at that node, and char `ch` .

```
struct node 
{
    int i;  
    char ch;
}
```

**ALGORITHM :**
When traversing the string , if it's not in trie , insert it in trie , else traverse down the trie and when string ends , do `i=i+1` , marking one more string ends here .

see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296618/what-is-the-most-common-use-of-the-trie-data-structure